# Dynamically filled HTML select, change selected visual . Blade Laravel template

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this code. I'm working in Blade template by Laravel framework.

```
<select class="form-control" name="id_zupanije" id="id_zupanije" onchange="popuniGradove(this, document.getElementById('id_grada'))">

@foreach($zupanije as $zupanija)

    @if($zupanija->id == $idzupanije)

        <option value="{{$zupanija->id}}" selected="selected">{{$zupanija->naziv_zupanije}}</option>

    @else

        <option value="{{$zupanija->id}}" selected="">{{$zupanija->naziv_zupanije}}</option>

    @endif

@endforeach

<option value="0" selected="">--Odaberite--</option>
```

idzupanije is id of the select option that needs to be selected...

javascript function "popuniGradove" is for creating select options for another select.

What I want to know is how to visual update selected option, so when window loads I see created select and showing me selected option, not this one
"--Odaberite--".

EDIT
here is screenshoot of how it looks..
[image: screenshoot1]

I have 3 selects.. first is Zupanija (eng. "province"), Grad (eng. City), Kvart (eng. quart).. when I select zupanija, select grad is filled with options -> cities that have foregin key id_zupanija in table .. samo for kvart, after city is selected, javascript creates options with proper kvarts
... After I press submit (bnt Filtriraj) I refresh the page and filter results below... but I want my selects to save their choosen options before before submiting.. they keep showing --Odaberite-- (default option, last created) afer submiting..

[image: ss2]

Comment: Do you need to update other select when you select a option of select with id id_zupanije?

Comment: yes, read my edit on the post :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you could consider using a Package like the old laravel 4 FormBuilder.

E. g. https://github.com/kristijanhusak/laravel-form-builder

That way you can bind every form to the respective model like so:

```
{!! Form::model($user, array('route' => array('user.update', $user->id))) !!}
```

Laravel automatically checks if input is existing in cache and will attach that data to the form.

Comment: I did a edit on a question.. I hope I explained it better now :)

Comment: Are you submitting with JavaScript or classical http reload?

Comment: post request. because there is 30 more filters in "advanced filters/more filters" ..

Comment: Try that package. It will automatically ouput the selects with the previous choice.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in documentation that I can add javascript functions in attributes, and HTML divs because my "advance filtering" div is hidden untill I press button "show more (vise opcija filtriranja" ..

Comment: You could add a data-property to your submit button like ```<button type="submit" data-show-more="{{ ($previous_choice) ? true : false }}"></button>```. Check that value in JavaScript and if it´s true display the show more button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 2 selectize, in this example we have first one for states (for example) and a second one for cities (for example). when we select a state the page send an ajax request to fetch cities in this state, then we set cities list on the cities' select.

the state select :

```
<select id="select-cities-state" class="selectized">
     <option value="1">State 1</option>
     ...
</select>
```

the cities select :

```
<select id="select-cities-city" class="selectized" disabled="">
     <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

```
var xhr;
var select_state, $select_state;
var select_city, $select_city;

$select_state = $('#select-cities-state').selectize({
    onChange: function(value) {
        if (!value.length) return;
        select_city.disable();
        select_city.clearOptions();
        select_city.load(function(callback) {
            xhr && xhr.abort();
            xhr = $.ajax({
                url: 'https://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=http://api.sba.gov/geodata/primary_city_links_for_state_of/' + value + '.json',
                success: function(results) {
                    select_city.enable();
                    callback(results);
                },
                error: function() {
                    callback();
                }
            })
        });
    }
});

$select_city = $('#select-cities-city').selectize({
    valueField: 'name',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: ['name']
});

select_city  = $select_city[0].selectize;
select_state = $select_state[0].selectize;

select_city.disable();
```